# Ffmpeg - creating thumbnail from webm format and converting webm movie to flv movie

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails

I have got a problem in which i want to
make a thumbnail from webm movie using ffmpeg.

I have this error when trying to make that
thumbnail:

"Unknown format is not supported
as input pixel format"

Furthermore i want to convert webm movie to
flv movie.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the ffmpeg command that's producing that error.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that your copy of ffmpeg has been compiled with support for webm, making a thumbnail should be as simple as:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -vframes 1 output.png
```

Perhaps with some `-s WxH` thrown in if you want the thumbnail to be smaller than the video.

Converting to flv is similarly simple:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm output.flv
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add "video/webm;" to the end of /usr/share/thumbnailers/ffmpegthumbnailer.thumbnailer